# I want to identify certain urls by attribute, but what if the attribute of interest is in foreign characters?

Tags: xpath, encoding, scrapy

I want to use Scrapy to scrape data recursively -- scraping data off of one page after the next. My spider needs to follow the "next page" button. In principle, the "next page" urls can be identified by `response.xpath("a[@title = 'next page']")`. Yet since the website is in Chinese (http://bxt.harbin.gov.cn/hrb_bzbxt/list_hf.php), the selector command I use is `response.xpath("a[@title = '下一页']")`. 下一页 means "next page." This wouldn't work, the error message being "ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters." The encoding of the website is gbk. So how can I select the "next page" urls for this Chinese website? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using unicode code point representation for '下一页' ( which is u'\u4e0b\u4e00\u9875' ) as shown :

```
next_page_link = response.xpath(u'//a[@title="\u4e0b\u4e00\u9875"]/@href')
if next_page_link: yield Request(next_page_link.extract()[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `@` to mean attribute -Try below-

```
response.xpath("//a[@title = '下一页']")
```

You may need to get response as unicode, details [here](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.TextResponse.body_as_unicode).